# Image in Delphi using SQL

Tags: sql, image, delphi, import

While working in Delphi, I want to take the link of a jpeg image that is in an Access database and display that image in the program. I feel i should be using a SQL statement but am unsure how to implement it. Thanks.

Comment: You can follow e.g. [`this tutorial`](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa030601a.htm).

Comment: Add it as an answer TLama, even you do not this usually :)

Comment: Anyone wants to expand on it can add it as an answer.